# Windows Remote-App Server 2012 Office 2013 User Settings not saved

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, terminal-server, remoteapp, microsoft-office-2013

I have a Windows Server 2012 with RemoteApps enabled. It's running the latest Patches etc.
It has Office 2013 installed and Excel and Word are shared to all users.
Now I got the Problem that after each Reboot all User Settings are lost.
I have a few users who pin previously opened Documents so they dont need to remember all Paths and those are all gone after Reboot. Also last opened Documents is empty and after a Server reboot it brings the office 2013 Window for First time setup where it asks if you want to connect to skydrive and all that.

In the RemoteApps Collection I enabled a Userprofile-Drive 100GB drive E: for Storing User profile data.
There is a Domain of course and there is no GPO Preventing the user from Storing settings etc.
We also got an older Terminal Server 2003 in the same Domain where this is not happening.

Any ideas why this is happening that all the Settings are lost after Reboot?

Comment: First place I would look is to see if the eventlog lists any errors related to userprofile or the userprofile disks.

Comment: Thanks but no there is no errors in it!